# Combine canvas and layout?

Tags: java, android

Presumably it must be quite common to desire a screen in which 
there are graphical elements (for which you may like to use a canvas) and widgets/buttons on the same screen. But everything I've looked at so far gives examples of either screens full of widgets *OR* whole screen canvases. Can someone point me to some example code for using both at the same time.

...or is this not the done thing?

**EDIT:** Following on from Steve's suggestion my code now looks like this:

```
public class CanLay extends Activity
{
    Bitmap bm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.canlay);

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ella);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        SurfaceView sv;
        SurfaceHolder sh;
        Canvas can = null;

        sv = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surview);
        sh = sv.getHolder();

        try
        {
            can = sh.lockCanvas(null);

            synchronized(sh)
            {
                can.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);         
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (can != null)
            {
                sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(can);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem now is that sh.lockCanvas(null); always returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any sample code, but you usually get a `Canvas` from a `SurfaceView`, which is a `View` like other widgets (eg, `TextView` and `Button`). I would try just laying out the `SurfaceView` along with the other elements of the layout. The your basic XML structure might look something like

```
<LinearLayout >
    <TextView />
    <Button />
    <SurfaceView />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
To get the `Canvas` from `SurfaceView`, first get the [`SurfaceHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html), then lock the canvas, draw your stuff, and unlock the canvas to have it displayed. In code that normally looks like:

```
SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
Canvas c = null;
try {
    c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
    synchronized(holder) {
        // draw here
        // c.drawBitmap() or whatever
    }
} finally {
    if(c != null) 
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
}
```

**DOUBLE EDIT:**
According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29), `lockCanvas` returns null when the surface isn't ready. When you're still in `onCreate()`, the surface is definitely not ready. The way you know a surface is ready is by handling a callback to [`SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html). (Games often use `surfaceCreated()` to know when to start running their non-event thread.)

I know this may sound like more and more stuff you have to do, but it's really not that bad. You can even do it inline with something like this:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflate the XML with setContentView(), create your Bitmap, etc

    sv = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surview);
    sv.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Canvas can;
            try {
                can = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized(holder) {
                    can.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);         
                }
            } finally {
                if(can != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(can);
            }
        }});

    // the rest of onCreate()
}
```

I may have messed up some of the braces, but you get the idea. Overall, it might be easier to put your `SurfaceHolder.Callback` implementation in its own non-anoymous class since there are restrictions on being anonymous, but that's the way you know your `SurfaceView` is ready for business. And of course, it's good to implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed()` so that you know when `SurfaceView` is going out of business. (Games often use `surfaceDestroyed()` to know when to stop running their non-event thread!)

Comment: Thanks, but How do you get a canvas from a surfaceview?

Comment: You can really just get the `SurfaceHolder` once at the beginning, and then get the `Canvas` every time you want to draw to it. Of course you get your `SurfaceView` from `findViewById()`.

Comment: I'm sure your suggestion is correct, but I'm still one cock-up short of getting it to work - see edit.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but if you want to be able to draw things along side other "widgets" simply create you're own View by extending View and implement what you want to draw in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method.  The Canvas is supplied to you.

Comment: @dbryson: I'm a beginner so this maybe BS, but what what about your call to setContentView()? If you pass the name of an xml file then you see all the widgets specified in the xml. If you pass the name of your custom view then how do you arrange for the buttons to appear?